# Filter documents that do not have a property set - Prisma

Tags: prisma

I have this example data:

```js
const example = [
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Husdady",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Vereth",
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: "Mikaela",
    age: 17
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    productId: 4,
    name: "Markus",
    age: 24
  },
  {
    productId: 8,
    name: "Cecilia",
    age: 18
  },
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Anton",
    age: 16
  }
]

console.log(example)
```

I have a 'User' model in prisma. So what I must achieve is to filter all those users that do not have a defined productId and also filter by productId.

For example, I want to filter all users that have product Id 1 and also all users that do not have a productId defined

I have tried with the following filter

```js
this.prisma.users.findMany({
  where: {
    OR: [
      { productId: undefined },
      { productId: 1 } 
    ]
  }
})
```

This query gets me all the users that have '1' as the value of their 'productId' but it does not bring me the users that do not have a defined productId.

The expected result of the above query would be:

```js
const result = [
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Husdady",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "Vereth",
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: "Mikaela",
    age: 17
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Anton",
    age: 16
  }
]

console.log(result)
```

I only get the users 'Husdady' and 'Anton'

```js
const resultObtained = [
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Husdady",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    productId: 1,
    name: "Anton",
    age: 16
  }
]

console.log(resultObtained)
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you try with `{ productId: null },` ?

Comment: Yes I tried but not is the expected result

Comment: Could you share this part of your schema?